# Get Instagram Bussiness Account - instagram_business_account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to make a get request to get instagram business_acount, in some of case I recieve a response in which indicates that I need more permissions.

Request: [https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{pageid}?fields=instagram_business_account&access_token={access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/%7Bpageid%7D?fields=instagram_business_account&access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)

Background:
In the past I was not able to receive a satisfactory answer, the answer I recieved was:

{
"error": {
"message": "(#100) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "xxxxxxxx"
}
}

So, I ask you "pages_read_engagement" permission and when you grant it, it start works for most of our clientes but not for all.

Nowadys:
I still have the error response for some client requests but not for all, only for a few of them:

{
"error": {
"message": "(#100) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "xxxxxxxx"
}
}

Please, "Could you give us the reasons for getting this error response although we have granted the correct permissions".

We have granted at least the following in the advannced mode:

instagram_basic
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement

We have not ask for the following because according with your documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/page/), with pages_read_engagement it is sufficient:

business_management
ads_management

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you share a list of the permissions you have? also, you know that when you grant a new permission, you have to create a new access token, right? and why do you use v9 instead of v14 as the version ?

Comment: Hi, We also try with newer api versions included v14. We use a permanent token so I think I don't have to regenerate it, with other permissions we had granted it was not necessary.

We have the following permissions granted as advanced access:

instagran_basic
pages read_engagement
pages_show_list
Business Asset User Profile Access
pages_managed_metadata
public_profile

thank you very much.

Comment: @user3227808 Please do you need instagram_basic to access Instagram chats in messenger?